# How to install (to disk) ChromeOS?

Tags: laptop, google-chrome, operating-systems, netbook, google-chrome-os

I have a HP Mini laptop that I wish to install ChromeOS. I used hexxen's lime build as my laptop's wireless was not supported by vanilla, and I used a USB stick. It works fine, but I can't figure out how to install it and overwrite my existing Windows installation, as currently it seems to be running as a live USB.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though this has been done by others before,
http://aikihomestead.blogspot.com/2010/02/google-chrome-os-on-asus-eeepc-2gb-surf.html